# PL/SQL [SQL Statement ignored]

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm having issues to add some code to my package file which is laying on the database. The issue that is being displayed by SQLPlus is "The SQL statement is ignored" but i am not able to track the issue.

It would be nice, if somebody of you out there, would help me, trying to figure out what the issue is.

Thanks in advance.

```
Function getLetterheadAndLayoutConf(p_invoice_type_code IN Varchar2,
                                p_admission_type_code IN Varchar2,
                                p_accounting_type_code IN Varchar2,
                                p_costbearer_id IN Number,
                                p_institute_id IN Number,
                                p_clearing_center_id IN Number,
                                p_deduction_defined_jn IN Varchar2,
                                p_letterhead_code OUT Varchar2,
                                p_layout_code OUT Varchar2)
Return Integer IS
v_Return                    Integer;
CURSOR cRechnungLetterheadLayout(p_p_invoice_type_code Varchar2,
                                 p_p_admission_type_code Varchar2,
                                 p_p_accounting_type_code Varchar2,
                                 p_p_costbearer_id Integer,
                                 p_p_institute_id Integer,
                                 p_p_clearing_center_id Integer,
                                 p_p_deduction_defined_jn Varchar2) IS
SELECT  allc_letterhead_code, allc_layout_code
    FROM acc_letterhead_layout_conf
   WHERE (    ( allc_invoice_type_code = p_p_invoice_type_code
               OR allc_invoice_type_code IS NULL
              )
          AND ( allc_admission_type_code = p_p_admission_type_code
                 OR allc_admission_type_code IS NULL
              )
          AND ( allc_accounting_type_code = p_p_accounting_type_code
                 OR allc_accounting_type_code IS NULL
              )
          AND ( allc_costbearer_id = p_p_costbearer_id
                 OR allc_costbearer_id IS NULL
              )
          AND ( allc_clearing_center_id = p_p_clearing_center_id
                 OR allc_clearing_center_id IS NULL
              )
          AND ( allc_deduction_defined_jn = p_p_deduction_defined_jn
                 OR allc_deduction_defined_jn IS NULL
              )
         )
     AND nvl(allc_institute_id, p_p_institute_id)
ORDER BY allc_institute_id DESC, allc_sort_no ASC;
Begin
if cRechnungLetterheadLayout%ISOPEN Then CLOSE cRechnungLetterheadLayout; End 
If;
OPEN cRechnungLetterheadLayout(p_invoice_type_code, p_admission_type_code, p_accounting_type_code,
                               p_costbearer_id, p_institute_id, p_clearing_center_id,
                               p_deduction_defined_jn);
FETCH cRechnungLetterheadLayout
 into p_layout_code,
      p_letterhead_code;
CLOSE cRechnungLetterheadLayout;
dbg.i(1, 'Vorgabe Letterhead = ''' || p_letterhead_code || '''');
dbg.i(1, 'Vorgabe Layout     = ''' || p_layout_code || '''');
v_Return := 1;
End getLetterheadAndLayoutConf;
```

Comment: The final predicate in the WHERE clause lacks an operator. `AND nvl(allc_institute_id, p_p_institute_id)` should be followed by `= something` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, i totally did not see that even though knowing it.